# Centering line scatterplot in plotly

Tags: python, graph, center, scatter-plot, plotly

I am creating a line scatter plot using plotly python API. There are old and new data plotted in y-axis with the date in the x-axis.I would like to center the graph such that one part of the graph is old data and another half of the graph is new data. How can this be done in plotly?In the attached image, the blue one represents old and orange represents new data. How old and new can be centered  such that one part of the graph is old data and another half of the graph is new data?
[Plotly_Line_Scatterplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Qm16.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on the manual axes example from the [Plotly documentation](https://plot.ly/python/axes/):

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

xold=[5, 6, 7, 8]
yold=[3, 2, 1, 0]
xnew=[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]
ynew=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

oldData = go.Scatter(xold, yold)
newData = go.Scatter(xnew, ynew)
data = [oldData, newData]
lenOld = max(xold) - min(xold)
lenNew = max(xnew) - min(xnew)
lenX = 2*max(lenOld,lenNew)
layout = go.Layout(
    xaxis=dict(
        range=[min(xnew)-lenX/2, min(xnew)+lenX/2]
    )
)
fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
plot_url = py.plot(fig, filename='axes-range-manual')
```

For simplicity I have used integers as x-values rather than using dates but the same principle will apply.

Please note, I don't have `plotly` installed at present so I haven't tested this code.

Comment: I hope this would work. Will check and update you. Thanks.

Comment: @Hamish Kumar: It occurred to me that I had calculated the x range incorrectly. The range is now correctly centered on the start of the new data.